# Pass date params from URL to filter a list of entries in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to build a 'featured posts' feature for my app. I got a table `posts` with a column `feature_date`. I'm trying to make it so that you can hit a URL structured as `/year/month/date` and display all entries with a feature_date that match the date in the URL.

My `routes.rb` is routing correctly to the posts controller:

```
match "/:year/:month/:day", to: 'posts#index', via: 'get', :constraints => { :year => /\d{4}/, :month => /\d{2}/, :day => /\d{2}/ }, :as => 'post_date'
```

However, I think I'm not using the `post_controller.rb` correctly:

```
def index
  @date = params[:year].to_s + "/" + params[:month].to_s + "/" + params[:day].to_s
  @featured_posts = Post.find_by(feature_date: @date)
end
```

This seems too inelegant to be the right way to do it in Ruby.

My view is breaking, but I think it's from the controller:

```
<% @featured_posts.each do |post| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= post.title %></td>
  <td><%= post.url %></td>
  <td><%= post.user.name %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Delete', post_path(post), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

The error it's throwing is `undefined method 'each' for #<Post:0x007f94393bc7a0>`, but I believe it's because `@featured_posts` is returning `nil` (I'm not sure how to confirm that, just seems to be the reason why .each would be an undefined method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `@featured_posts = Post.find_by(feature_date: @date)` returns a single record and not an array of records as you expected. It is not because @featured_posts is nil otherwise the error would have been undefined method 'each' for NilClass. You could use `Post.find(:all, :conditions => {featured_date: @date}` but this will give a deprecation warning in Rails 4 and so would `Post.all(:conditions => {featured_date: @date})`

To fix that use this instead.

```
@featured_posts = Post.where(featured_date: @date).to_a
```

The .to_a makes it surely return an array.